# Import and export JIRA requirements

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Until now we based our development work on Word documents. Is there an effective way to import the contents of these documents as requirements / issues into JIRA and use JIRA for requirement management, only exporting them to documents when really necessary?

Comment: Are you talking about the Jama plug-in for Jira? Have you talked with Jama directly?

Comment: No, not yet. I'm not talking about any specific plugins, just wonder what I could use to generate issues based on a Word document containing tables of a certain format.

Comment: It's possible to create your own Java plug-in that would delve into the Word document and extract the content of the tables. Depending on the size of the project, it may be worthwhile expending the effort to do this. OTOH, it might be simpler to export the Word document into Excel. Then follow the instructions here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Importing+Data+from+CSV

Comment: @BobDalgleish, could you please make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you own docs are well structured you will be able to import them via @Bob Dalgleish 's solution proposal.

You will need to convert your files to CSVs, map all "keys" in your current structure to the one described in the [guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Importing+Data+from+CSV#ImportingDatafromCSV-PreparingyourCSVfile) and check your file's structure. Then you will be able to import them.
  Something more, you have the ability to import attachments. This way you can attach both the original document and resulting CSV file to each newly-created issue. This way you will have a nice backup of your "old document system". If you are considering doing such a transition between different organizational workflows use it as a read-only backup.

Comment: Thank you, we finally decided to do something like this except that by default we won't create new docs to the yet-to-be-created issues.

Comment: No problem, the important thing is to help each other out and not always answer just for the reputation points.